# Navigate to div section of a different html page using javascript in href

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript function to jump to a div section on the current html page(system_details.html):

```
<a href="javascript:show_processor()">Processor</a>
<a href="javascript:show_ram()">RAM</a>
```

However, I want to directly navigate to system_details.html page's `show_ram()` function from a different html page (index.html)

Comment: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479511/So-You-Want-A-Page-Jump-Huh.htm

Answer (score 0):

Give the links and id `<a href="javascript:show_ram()" id="ram">RAM</a>`. Add this `id` at the end of the URL using a hash like so `index.html#ram`.

Then use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.hash) $('#' + window.location.hash).click();
});
```

This will take the last part of the URL after the hash as the `id` of the link to be clicked on, and then call `click()` on the link with the specified `id`.

Comment: I have updated the answer, as I realised I didn't understand the original question correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Use ajax concept. Load data from index.html page