# Page scrolls down when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, anchor

I have a problem with pages scrolling down when clicking on my links. I'm pretty sure it's because the browser thinks the link is supposed to be an anchor to a certain area on the page.

I'm using this jquery code to hide the main div and show the div corresponding to the link clicked. The main info div and main info2 divs are the same in css. The only thing different is the text inside.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#home").click(function(){
 $("#main_info2").hide();
 $("#main_info").show();
});
$("#info").click(function(){
 $("#main_info").hide();
 $("#main_info2").show();
});
$("#gyms").click(function(){
 $("#main_info").hide();
 $("#main_info2").show();
 });
$("#contact").click(function(){
 $("#main_info").hide();
 $("#main_info2").show();
});
});
```

Here is my navigation list:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home" id="home"><img src="main home page/purhome.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#info" id="info"><img src="main home page/purinfo.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#gyms" id="gyms"><img src="main home page/purgyms.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" id="contact"><img src="main home page/purcontact.jpg"></a></li>
```

When I click on the info link for example the home div hides and the info div is shown, but the page scrolls down due to the `href="#info"`. If I change it to `href="#"` it works fine without scroll, however, the browser url does not reflect the div that is showing if only using the `"#"`.

For example, I want the browser to show `http://google/index.php#info` and not just `http://google/index.php#`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly are you using href for? Are you saying that you don't want it to scroll down to that div when it is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

In this line:

```
<a href="#home" id="home"><img src="main home page/purhome.jpg"></a>
```

You are setting up a link which indeed scrolls to a certain area on the page, in this case to itself.

`href="#home"` means: when clicked on this link make the element with the `id` of `home` visible.

The actual link which is clicked, has the `id` of `home`.

So it ensures that whatever is inside itself is visible, browsers usually scroll down the page to the specific element with the specified `id`. This explains the behaviour.

In your case you can just get rid of the `href` attribute on the links, that should fix it.

**Edit**

The easiest way for you to get the desired behaviour is to just change your `id`'s to something like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home" id="home-link"><img src="main home page/purhome.jpg"></a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#home-link").click(function() {
  $("#main_info2").hide();
  $("#main_info").show();
});
...
```

And you could even change the `id` of `main_info` to `home` to ensure `main_info` (or `home` then) is visible after clicking the link, if that is the kind of behaviour you are after.

**Edit 2 - reading the hash solution**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home"><img src="main home page/purhome.jpg"></a></li>
  ...
</ul>
<div id="home">This is the tab content for the "home" tab.</div>
```

No `id` needed on the link, but set one on the `<div>` or on whatever element you use to create your tab content. Now the `href` attribute on the link will ensure the right thing happens in combination with the JavaScript below which catches the click and shows the right tab based on the hash value .

**JavaScript**

```
$("a").click(function() {
  // Hide all tab content elements.
  $('some-selector-which-selects-all-tab-content-elements').hide(); 
  // Show only the tab content element with an id equal to the hash value.
  $(window.location.hash).show();   
});
```

Comment: One problem i do have now is say I click the info link from the home page. The main div disappears and now the 2nd div shows. The url says localhost/index.php#info. But, when i refresh, the page goes back to showing the main div but keeps the same url. So you have the main div but the url says you're on the info page

Comment: Yes, you could fix that by reading the hash (the bit after the #) with JavaScript and then using jQuery to trigger a click on the link with the related `id` after the page has loaded. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16074578/1846192) for some example code. In your case it should be something like `$('#' + window.location.hash + '-link').click();`. It's a better approach all together, that way you won't need your current jQuery code.

Comment: Just click the link, then catch the hash and open the right `div` with jQuery based on that hash value.

Comment: So something like this? 'function getHash() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  return hash.substring(1); // remove #
}'

Comment: Then use this: $('#' + window.location.hash + '-link').click(); 
Except add my click function to specify which div to open?

Comment: I have edited the answer to show you how to do that, you might have to change it a little bit as I don't know how you've set things up exactly, but it should get you onto the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're assigning click event handlers to the a tags there's no need to use the 'href' attributes in your code:

```
<a id="home">
```